# Remove a function from the stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a big issue with my code

I have a function called "delayCallFuntions":

```
function delayCallFuntions(delay: int, func: Function) {
  var timer: Timer = new Timer(delay, 1);
  timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, func);
  timer.start();
}
```

And I used this function like below to make connection between 2 point in my screen:

```
delayCallFuntions(1, function (e: Event) {timer011(wireColor);});
```

And function "timer011" is making the connections:

```
function timer011(firstColor: int): void {
wireColor = firstColor;
//GRID is a class
//Path A to B
var PathAB: Grid;
PathAB = new Grid(4, 5, 20, 17, canvas, wireColor);
this.addChild(PathAB);
```

}

My problem is:
I have several of these functions like "timer012", "timer013", ... that they need to execute one after another.
When I go out of this scene and come back again, these is still some of these functions are working while I need them to start from the beginning and go one by one.

for example: when i come back, "timer011" is starting while "timer016" is also completing at the same time.

hope someone can help me as this problem made me frustrated.

Comment: Can you explain a little better what your program is trying to accomplish.  Sounds like you just want to queue up some functions in a delayed chain?  So one executes, then 1 second later the next one etc..     And you want to be able to stop that chain if the user moves out of the scene/frame?

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis The functions "timer011", "timer012" etc. are to meke different connection between different cells in my Grid. they need to be executed based on timer. For instance: timer011 is executed after 100ms and timer012 executed after 3000ms until the end. i want them to be stopped when the user wants to go to the other scene.

Comment: You need to save the reference to the initial **Timer** object and stop it and destroy it when you don't need it any longer. Also, I usually create a field **destroyed:Boolean** and start methods with **if (destroyed) return;**, so when I don't need some content any longer and cannot ensure its immediate disposal (like delayed calls, listeners etc), then I set **destroyed = true;** to prevent these methods from being executed at the wrong time.

Comment: @Organis can you please give a practical example? I have tried to put flag for it, but it didn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are creating a whole new timer everytime you add a function.  That timer will stay in memory because of the event listener, and since it's encapsulated in the function, you have no easy way to reference it again to stop them.

What would be a better approach, is to create just one timer globally referenced so you can stop it if needed.

Here is a way you could accomplish this:

```
//create an array that will hold all the functions you are planning on calling
var delayedFuncs:Array = [];

//this var will be used to store the current function that will be called next
var currentFuncObj:Object = null; //set it to null so it clears the value when you return to this frame

//create a single, global timer reference for everything
//don't initialize it here though
//if you revisit this frame, you don't want to create a whole new timer, but keep using the previous one
var funcTimer:Timer;

//if the timer has already been created (you've been to this frame before), stop it
if (funcTimer) {
    funcTimer.stop();
}else {
//if you haven't been to this frame before, create the timer and add the listener
    funcTimer = new Timer(1,1);
    funcTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, nextFunc, false, 0, true);
}

//this function adds items to your queue. I've added the ability to also include parameters 
function delayCallFunctions(delay:int, func:Function, ... funcParams):void {
    //add an object to the array that stores the function, delay, and any parameters to pass to that function
    delayedFuncs.push({delay: delay, func: func, params: funcParams});

    //if the timer hasn't started running yet, start it since we've added something
    if(!funcTimer.running) nextFunc();
}

//this function runs when the timer completes
function nextFunc(e:Event = null):void {

    //if we have an existing function to call, call it
    if (currentFuncObj){
        //invoke the function with the parameters
        currentFuncObj.func.apply(null, currentFuncObj.params);
    }

    //if there are still items in the array, grab the next one
    if(delayedFuncs.length > 0){
        //array.shift grabs the first element in the array and removes it from the array
        currentFuncObj = delayedFuncs.shift();

        //reset the timer
        funcTimer.reset();
        //set the appropriate delay
        funcTimer.delay = currentFuncObj.delay;
        //start the timer again
        funcTimer.start();
    }
}
```

So now, you'd use by doing:

```
delayCallFunctions(3000, trace, "hello", "world", "I'll be traced 3 seconds from now");
delayCallFunctions(2000, trace, "I'll be called 2 seconds after the last one");
```

Or, with your specific code:

```
delayCallFuntions(1000, timer011, wireColor);
```

Now at any time (say you hit a button to go to change scenes), you can just stop the global timer.

```
funcTimer.stop();
```

Comment: it is working properly but i everything to be started again when i come back to the scene! Now, by this code, the last delay will be remain and when i come back to the previous scene, the second one will be started at the same time with the first one because it is already pushed to the array and the delay will not be 0 again! is there any way that i can fix it?

Comment: Sorry, yes, initializing the `currentFuncObj` as null should fix that.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: it is properly working, Thank you so much :-) can I ask another question related to a Sprite type of variable?